# Software para fazer query's JPA

Tags: hibernate, jpa

Existe algum cliente (like:  pgadmin3, Oracle SQL Developer, Mysql Workbench) 
para fazer consultas em JPQL?

Eu tenho um projeto que usa jpa, e preciso debugar as jpql's geradas.

Eu vi que o Squirrel faz isso, mas para HQL.

Comment: Não ficou claro... você quer executar JPQL através de um software? Ou quer ver a JPQL transformada em SQL?

Comment: Eu quero executar JPQL através de um software.

Answer (score 1):

Existe um modo de você poder executar sua JPQL sem precisar de um software para isso: http://uaihebert.com/como-testar-sua-jpql-hql-sem-realizar-deploy/

Você adiciona uma classe que vai criar o contexto do JPA em memória e pedir para que a JPQL seja testada em um prompt (é possível ver o código no post acima).

Se sua empresa tiver condição, a ide IDEA Intellij tem essa função nativamente.